# Columns in HTML5/CSS3 with Sublime

Tags: css, html, sublimetext, multiple-columns

I am using sublime 2 as a text editor and it doesn't seem to recognize some of the traditional column keywords. I was wondering if anyone could tell me the best way to create columns (from scratch). I want to learn how to do it before I use a existing framework. The flex-box and column count both are not recognized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this, you'll want to install package control first

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions

Comment: let me know if you need help getting package control installed

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with creating HTML columns?

Comment: it sounds like OP is not getting intellisense for flex-box and columns (css3), this package brings such intellisense. Based on her score and the lack of answers it looks like nobody clearly understands the question (myself included). Please don't downvote unless you without having a better solution or an understanding of how I'm wrong

Comment: Thanks godmode. I downloaded the package and it seemed to work fine. (I think I was afraid if the text editor didn't recognize something, it wouldn't work at all. But I've learned that code is code.) I think I understand the basic html, but was having trouble on the css side and getting my columns to line up next to each other, and not on top. I used a flex display and I think that did the trick. I am still having some trouble with the box-sizing - I don't think it does anything to change my style. But with the display: flex I was able to get what I needed.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help, feel free to send me any other questions you have